# Correct way to octal escape a UTF-8 character in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

I need to get the octal escape sequence for UTF-8 characters in Python and was wondering whether there's any simpler way of doing what I want to do, e.g. something in the standard library that I overlooked. I have a makeshift string manipulation function but I'm hoping there is a better solution.

I want to get from (e.g.):

To: `\360\220\205\245`

Right now I'm doing this:

```
char = '\U00010165' # this is how Python hands it over to me
char = str(char.encode())    
# char = "b'\xf0\x90\x85\xa5'"

arr = char[4:-1].split(“\\x”)
# arr = ['f0', '90', '85', 'a5']

char = ''
for i in arr:
    char += '\\' + str(oct(int(i,16)))

# char = \0o360\0o220\0o205\0o245
char = char.replace("0o", "")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please do try to paste actual code next time; it's a bit of a pain having to replace all the fancy quotes with ASCII quotes that Python would actually recognize as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `format(i, '03o')` to format to octal numbers without leading `0o` indicator, or `str.format()` to include the literal backslash too:

```
>>> format(16, '03o')
'020'
>>> '\\{:03o}'.format(16)
'\\020'
```

and just loop over the encoded `bytes` value; each character is yielded as an integer:

```
char = ''.join(['\\{:03o}'.format(c) for c in char.encode('utf8')])
```

Demo:

```
>>> char = '\U00010165'
>>> ''.join(['\\{:03o}'.format(c) for c in char.encode('utf8')])
'\\360\\220\\205\\245'
>>> print(''.join(['\\{:03o}'.format(c) for c in char.encode('utf8')]))
\360\220\205\245
```