# How to force Python Requests send multipart/form-data filenames in octal-escaped style for Unicode characters?

Tags: python, unicode, http-headers, python-requests, file-transfer

Python Requests http://docs.python-requests.org send multipart/form-data encoded form data with

```
filename*=utf-8''%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F.jpg
```

style filenames in Content-Disposition block for unicode-named files. My server doesn't recognize it. What I need is

```
filename="\320\270\320\274\321\217.jpg"
```

style for unicode characters.

What should I do?

I send my POST request in this way now:

```
file=open('name.jpg','rb')
r=requests.post(url, files={
                     'files[]':('имя.jpg', file, 'image/jpeg')
                           })
```

here `имя.jpg` is original view of encodings above.

I tried to encode it manually with

```
'имя.jpg'.encode('utf8').decode('latin1').encode('unicode-escape').decode('latin1')
```

sequence, but Requests still hate backslash-characters and URL-encode them prefixing with that unrecognizable `filename*=utf-8''`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to octal escape a UTF-8 character in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858021/correct-way-to-octal-escape-a-utf-8-character-in-python)

Comment: @snakecharmerb no, just like I said in my question, Requests still hate backslash-characters and URL-encode them prefixing with that unrecognizable `filename*=utf-8''` so it's not working just to put correctly octal-encoded string into filename.

Comment: Does your server's documentation provide any technical specification for what it will accept for non-ascii filenames?